# Do all factions in Endless Legend have at least one viable win condition?

Tags: endless-legend

(Bear with me, I'll try to whip the question into something answerable by SE standards)

Related to [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/252888/are-there-any-factions-that-are-clearly-over-underpowered), my buddies and I are trying to get some EL going—one challenge from previous 4X is that lack of balance usually meant lack of replay-ability for us (so, people who get stuck with weaker factions don't have much incentive to play). So:

**Do all factions have at least one viable win condition?**
From what I've read, Diplomatic Victory is almost impossible, but maybe Drakken can still win through other means by imposing peace/alliances on other players and developing their kingdom.

If so, please elaborate on those (i.e., Vaulters: Conquest/Supremacy/Elimination victories, thank to strategic resource production/boosts, that allow bigger/better armies, all other things being equal; Ardent Mages, due to Pillars/Incantations).

Comment: Good luck getting a proper answer to this. I don't play multiplayer at all, but in my experience the Vaulters are so much better than most of the other factions it's laughable.

Comment: I know it's a stretch, not sure if I should've cut the question up over several posts (to make each more tractable).

Comment: This seems much too opinionated to be answerable.  Question 4 is clearly off-topic, as well.

Comment: @ All that are following this thread, Q4 that @Frank mentions is now Q3 after I've combined the previous 2-3. @ Khashir - I'd consider splitting 1 and 2 into their own questions. Q1 seems fairly answerable, Q2 would seem to be bordering on opinion but I don't know enough about the game to make a call about it. Q3, as Frank states, is off-topic

Comment: Thanks, @Robotnik. I removed Q3, and cut out Q2 to a separate question.

Comment: @Khashir - No problem. I updated the title to reflect this :)

Comment: Much obliged, sir :).