# Are there any factions that are clearly over/underpowered?

Tags: endless-legend

As a follow-up to [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/252851/do-all-factions-in-endless-legend-have-at-least-one-viable-win-condition?noredirect=1#comment350804_252851), my initial impressions/readings suggest Wild Walkers lose out in mid-late game (but maybe can secure an early advantage?), whereas Drakken/Vaulters/Ardent Mages are seen as powerful.

Is there a fairly wide consensus in the community? Maybe not an overall ranking, but usually people agree on the extremes. Feel free to link to well-written thoughts/discussions on the matter.

Thanks!

Comment: IMO, all factions are both under and over powered: they all seem to have some sort of "cheat" and some sort of "weakness."  I've passed the game with all of them (even the there expansion factions); I find some a lot easier than others... but it's because of personal play style, not balance.  (Opinion, not answer.)